# Keep variables inside test class for next test in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to structure my pytests in a class to test a pipeline where I load and modify the data. To do so I created something like the below example. But the second test fails because `self.data` is still `None`.

```
class TestClass:
    data = None

    def test_load_data(self):
        self.data = [1, 2, 3]
        assert isinstance(self.data, list)

    def test_modify_data(self):
        self.data.append(4)
        assert len(self.data) is 4
```

Why is this not working and how do I pass the content of one test to another?

Comment: Have you tried initiating self.data in a constructor?

Comment: Apart from the fact that it's usually not a good idea to have this kind of test dependencies, you are assigning the list to an instance variable instead of the class variable. You need `self.__class__.data = [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @Blackgaurd yes, if you create an `def __init__(self)` function, it will not recognize the class as a testclass anymore. This makes also no sense to me yet.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen: Thanks a lot, this works. So better practice would be to really create unique input and output variables for each test functions I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you have the same problem, this is how I solved it according to the comment of [@MrBean Bremen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12480730/mrbean-bremen):

```
class TestClass:
    data = None

    def test_load_data(self):
        self.__class__.data = [1, 2, 3]
        assert isinstance(self.data, list)

    def test_modify_data(self):
        self.__class__.data.append(4)
        assert len(self.data) is 4
```

Make sure that you think about if it really is best practice for you, to reuse and change variables over multiple tests.

Comment: Really confused why such ugly solutions are needed for such a common usecase. Why would somebody define a class if he wouldn't also intend to use them in the classe's functions.